# Неудачное соединение с IMAP сервером

Tags: centos

Здравствуйте,

При попытке авторизации через Webmail (используется RoundCube), получаю ошибку: "Неудачное соединение с IMAP сервером"

При выполнении команды:<code>telnet 127.0.0.1 143</code>

Вижу следующее:<code>Trying 127.0.0.1...telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refusedtelnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused</code>

Пытался запустить IMAP:<code>service courier-imap start</code>

Результат тот же.

Команда:<code>ps ax | grep courier</code>

Выводит:<code> 6546 ?        S      0:00 /usr/libexec/courier-authlib/authdaemond 6565 ?        S      0:00 /usr/libexec/courier-authlib/authdaemond 6842 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep courier</code>

Я не очень силен в администрировании серверов, пытался нагуглить решение проблемы, но решение не нашел.

Кто может подсказать в чем может быть проблема, в какую сторону копать ?

Как можно проверить работоспособность IMAP сервера ?

Спасибо.

Comment: @walik, а что говорит команда "netstat -ltun", 143-й порт присутствует в списке?

Comment: Нет, 143 порта в списке нету.

Comment: Это говорит о том, что у вас не запускается Courier Mail Server. Попробуйте выполнить "service courier-imap status" - может прояснит ситуацию, если нет, то смотрите его логи.

Comment: Да, показывает что сервис не запущен:"courier-imap is stopped"То есть получается что не реагирует на команду "service courier-imap start"Отображается: "Starting Courier-Imap:" и все.Сейчас попробую нагуглить место хранения логов и посмотреть что там есть.

Comment: Обычно это место — /var/log/………

Comment: Нашел вроде нужные логи, там куча всего, толком и не разобрался где то что мне надо, но вроде это:hostname: Unknown hosthostname: Unknown hosttcpserver: fatal: unable to figure out port number for /usr/sbin/pop3logintcpserver: fatal: unable to figure out port number for /usr/sbin/imaplogintcpserver: fatal: unable to figure out port number for /usr/bin/couriertlstcpserver: fatal: unable to figure out port number for /usr/bin/couriertls

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить отroot "cat /var/log/messages|grep imapd"

Comment: Попробовал, ничего не выводится.Вычитал попробовать команду "hostname -f", она мне возвращает "hostname: Unknown host". Может в этом вся проблема ?   только не могу понять, как это не может определить хост ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кончился лимит на комментарии - поэтому ответом.hostname -f просто покажет имя вашего хоста. Если она говорит unknown, значит вы его не настроили, поэтому и не может определить. Вы бы поподробней что-ли излагали: где вычитали, попробовать что-бы что?Что у вас в /etc/sysconfig/network ?

Comment: В /etc/sysconfig/network  у меня:NETWORKING=yesNETWORKING_IPV6=yesHOSTNAME=moy.domenGATEWAY=ip.addressНо как я понял с хостом нет проблем, так как иначе не работал бы ни DNS и ничего другого.